# How to make checkedboxlist multiple columns

Tags: vb.net, checkedlistbox

I am using VS2008 on my home computer to develop a windows form application.

I need to use a CheckedListBox, here is the current CheckedListBox:

[image]

I am wondering how can I make it showing two or more columns instead of one at the time.

It would be really appreciated if you can share some code snippets.

Thank you.

Comment: [MultiColumn Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you JQSOFT, it is just that simple!!! Please put up your answer here and I will accept it.

Comment: Most welcome. Next time thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a two column control, either use a DataGridView or a ListView control. By setting a ListView control's View property to View.Details, you can use it as a multicolumn grid.